# Running time of the same statement differs so much in Java

Tags: java, time

I just worte a programm in **java** to test the time spent in executing myQsort.

part of the code looks like this:

```
long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
new sort().myQsort(a, 0, 100000 - 1);
long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

I loop the statements five times to get five timeSpent (t2-t1) and print them out, but the the results are strange, **everytime the first timeSpent appears lager than the rest**

---

Quick Sort in Java:

Round1: 30ms

Round2: 9ms

Round3: 9ms

Round4: 11ms

Round5: 9ms

Average time spent: 13ms

---

I have tried reading the 5 input files in a different order, or even reading the same file for 5 times. But the results are all similar. I also tried running the code on a different computer, while the result is still the same.


Can anyone explain why this happened?

Question Solved
Thanks for all the answers, I've tried add -Xint to the VM settings (inorder to shut down the JIT), and this time everying works pretty well.

---

Quick Sort in Java:

Round1: 61ms

Round2: 68ms

Round3: 72ms

Round4: 73ms

Round5: 59ms

Average time spent: 66ms

---

Thanks again for all your answers, it helps a lot :)

Comment: I think the primary reason is for the Java JIT Compiler

Comment: Garbage Collection, JIT, system/OS overheads...

Comment: The first time you run it, this is a cold start, meaning that Java loads in the code for the first time. The second time it is already in memory. As you can see the time does not vary that much after the first time.

Answer (score 4):

The first time you run it, this is a cold start, meaning that Java loads in the code of the program and its own code for the first time.

The second time it is already in memory. As you can see the time does not vary that much after the first time.

Furthermore milliseconds may vary by events that happen. For instance something is send to you through the network, your OS needs to modify an important table, etc.

Comment: Get it, I have tried shutting down the JIT and this time every timeSpent came out the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from JIT compilation, another factor may be the state of your list to be sorted.
Just like Quicksort performs worst if the list is already sorted, your sorting algorithm may perform best if the list is already sorted.

So, you may want to make sure that your sorting algorithm did not change the state of the list or you need to make copies of your list before starting your tests.

Comment: I assume these were separate runs (with the same input data or randomly generated data).

Comment: It's mentioned in the question that he/she "loop the statements five times". So, I think that might be a possible cause as well.

Comment: Actually, I read the file separately in each loop without making any changes to the original copy, so the state of the list was not changed...I'll try shutting down the JIT to see whether the result changes